# Recursive Function in TypeScript - Parents Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I want to create a recursive function that receive a List of objects that contains the id and parent_id. If the parent of an element is in the list I want to remove it and add it to the parent.

Convert this:

```
{
  "id": 180,
  "children": [],
  "parent_id": 195,
  "name": "Object 180"
},
{
  "id": 193,
  "children": [],
  "parent_id": 180,
  "name": "Object 193"
},
{
  "id": 194,
  "children": [],
  "parent_id": 180,
  "name": "Object 194"
}
{
  "id": 199,
  "children": [],
  "parent_id": 187,
  "name": "Object 199"
}
{
  "id": 304,
  "children": [],
  "parent_id": 193,
  "name": "Object 304"
}
```

To this:

```
{
  "id": 180,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 193,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 304,
          "children": [],
          "parent_id": 193,
          "name": "Object 304"
         }
      ],
      "parent_id": 180,
      "name": "Object 193"
    },
    {
      "id": 194,
      "children": [],
      "parent_id": 180,
      "name": "Object 194"
    }
  ],
  "parent_id": 195,
  "name": "Object 180"
},
{
  "id": 199,
  "children": [],
  "parent_id": 187,
  "name": "Object 199"
}
```

Sometimes the parent_id is null, and there is no limit of levels of the parents.

Comment: the result is an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since basarat's answer does not account for items nested more than one level.

Here a solution that creates an output with arbitrary nesting-depth:

```js
const listToTree = (input) => {
  const map = new Map(input.map((item) => [item.id, item]));
  
  const output = [];
  for (const item of input) {
    if (map.has(item.parent_id)) {
      map.get(item.parent_id).children.push(map.get(item.id));
    } else {
      output.push(map.get(item.id));
    }
  }
  return output;
};

const input = [
  {
    "id": 180,
    "value": 10,
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": 195,
    "name": "Object 180"
  },
  {
    "id": 193,
    "value": 10,
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": 180,
    "name": "Object 193"
  },
  {
    "id": 194,
    "value": 10,
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": 180,
    "name": "Object 194"
  },
  {
    "id": 199,
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": 187,
    "name": "Object 199"
  },
  {
    "id": 304,
    "value": 10,
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": 193,
    "name": "Object 304"
  },
  {
    "id": 305,
    "value": 10,
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": 194,
    "name": "Object 304"
  }
];

const output = listToTree(input);

console.log(output);
```

### Edit: Aggregate values

If you want to aggregate values along ancestry chains of the resulting tree I would recommend to do this in a separate function afterwards. This will keep your code cleaner, easier to test and more readable.

The implementation depends on whether or not your input-array is sorted (children before parents). If you want to process unordered inputs you have to loop through the each ancestry chain.

```js
function aggregateValue(branch) {
  const children = branch.children || [];
  return children.reduce((sum, child) => sum + aggregateValue(child), branch.value || 0);
}

function aggregateValueAlongBranches(tree) {
  return tree.map((branch) => {
    return {
      ...branch,
      aggregatedValue: aggregateValue(branch),
      children: aggregateValueAlongBranches(branch.children),
    };
  });
}

const input = [
  {
    "id": 180,
    "value": 10,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 193,
        "value": 10,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 304,
            "value": 10,
            "children": [],
            "parent_id": 193,
            "name": "Object 304"
          }
        ],
        "parent_id": 180,
        "name": "Object 193"
      },
      {
        "id": 194,
        "value": 10,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 305,
            "value": 10,
            "children": [],
            "parent_id": 194,
            "name": "Object 304"
          }
        ],
        "parent_id": 180,
        "name": "Object 194"
      }
    ],
    "parent_id": 195,
    "name": "Object 180"
  },
  {
    "id": 199,
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": 187,
    "name": "Object 199"
  }
];
const output = aggregateValueAlongBranches(input);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that we need a recursive function. Can I use a funcion in this to stack the value of the children? Ex: parent_value = child_1.value + child_2.value

Comment: You mean to add an additional field to each item containing the full path? Like `${rootItem.id}.${child1.id}.${child2.id}` ? There is a common pattern to model trees with `ancestors`, check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/) out. It might be more useful to keep it in a field like: `ancestors: ['root_ancestor_id', 'first_ancestor_id', 'second_ancestor_id']`. Meaning, this item is a child of 'second_ancestor' which is a child of 'first_ancestor' which is a child of 'root_ancestor' which does not have a parent.

Comment: I mean, for exemple, the amount of money the family has and add to the parent. Ex: in the list the grandfather has $4, father $2, son $1. After the Tree convertion the grandfather has $7, the father has $3 and the son has $1. All parents has the children's money.

Comment: @WalberAmorim, better do this in a separate function. I added an example

Comment: Thanks for the help! You saved me :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* a recursive function. Just track items you've already seen and if parent exists in it add to `parent.children` or add a new root node.

An example complete solution is attached.

## Complete code

```
type Item = {
    id: number,
    children: Item[],
    parent_id: number,
    name: string,
}

const items: Item[] = [
    {
        "id": 180,
        "children": [],
        "parent_id": 195,
        "name": "Object 180"
    },
    {
        "id": 193,
        "children": [],
        "parent_id": 180,
        "name": "Object 193"
    },
    {
        "id": 194,
        "children": [],
        "parent_id": 180,
        "name": "Object 194"
    },
    {
        "id": 199,
        "children": [],
        "parent_id": 187,
        "name": "Object 199"
    },
    {
        "id": 304,
        "children": [],
        "parent_id": 193,
        "name": "Object 304"
    }
];


function nest(items:Item[]): Item[] {
  const output: Item[] = [];
  const idToItem = new Map<number,Item>();
  for (let item of items) {
      // Either add to parent. Or create a new root level node
      if (idToItem.has(item.parent_id)) {
          idToItem.get(item.parent_id)!.children.push(item);
      } else {
          idToItem.set(item.id, item);
          output.push(item);
      }
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(nest(items));
```

Comment: This solution ignores nested children